# Keygenme - Key location

Tags: ida, x86, crackme

So I was messing with an interesting keygenme, written in C++, which derives the key based on the values of the [OSINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/osinfo-structure) structure. Now, when checking for a valid key it uses the following instruction:

`CMP EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[key]`

My question is: why isn't the key stored in a local variable or something like:`[EBP-X]`?

How would I translate it back into C++ so that it stores the key in `DS:[key]` rather than in the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a global or static variable.

Explanation:

`EBP` (base pointer) typically holds the address of the current stack frame, in that case it's used to get the address to local variable. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15020825/5267751)) Global or static variables don't need such pointer, as their address is fixed on program load.

---

By the way: I didn't test compiling a simple program on a 32-bit compiler. [64-bit mode doesn't use segment registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165678/why-64-bit-mode-long-mode-doesnt-use-segment-registers).